# Unable to retrieve relational data with object id

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve a list of posts (_Relation ) that are stored as a relation in a parse class called "Threads". I tried many different usages but didn't succeed though the object Id and the getClassName methods are working I am unable to get the list.

```
    ParseRelation<ParseObject> posts = recylerViewListAdapter.currentThreadObject.threadObject.getRelation("postMessage");
            ParseQuery postsQuery = posts.getQuery();

            Log.d("DEBUG_NETWORK_CALL : ", String.valueOf(postsQuery.getClassName())); // This works and I get the class name as "Posts" while debugging.

// The List size retrieved is 0 when I print it


            postsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(List list, ParseException e) {
                    List<postModelStore> postModelStoreArrayList = new ArrayList<postModelStore>();
                    Log.d("DEBUG_NETWORK_RETRIEVAL : ","DONE");
                    Log.d("DEBUG_NETWORK_LIST_SIZE : ",String.valueOf(list.size()));
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject parseObject = (ParseObject) list.get(i);
                        String postMessage = (String) parseObject.get("postMessage");
                        Log.d("post Message", postMessage);
                        ParseUser parseUser = (ParseUser) parseObject.get("postedBy");
                        String profilePictureUrl = "local";
                        profilePictureUrl = ((ParseFile) parseUser.get("profilePicture")).getUrl();
                        postModelStore retrievedPostDetails = new postModelStore(postMessage, profilePictureUrl);
                        postModelStoreArrayList.add(retrievedPostDetails);
                    }
                    postListObject = postModelStoreArrayList;
                }

                @Override
                public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
                    callMe();
                }
            });
```